# Will facebook always send email of the user who is loggin in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth

I am using omniauth ( https://github.com/intridea/omniauth ) to allows users to log in via facebook. everthing is working. However I just want to sure that facebook is always send email address of the user all the time.

Is there as way to control that facebook must send email address.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they do not always send the email. This is controlled via permissions. I have seen a real user on my OAuth website show without an email. You have to handle this case.

Comment: Another thing to beware of is that sometimes they will send a proxy email address for the user using Facebook's domain. If it's important to get their real address, you'll need to inspect the address Facebook responds with instead of just checking for the existence of a value.